# Compare List element with a string in python pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

```
_LIST=[]
J=1
for i,r in df.iterrows():
   _VAR=r["A"]
if (_VAR==_LIST[J-1]):
```

I just want to compare _VAR value to the value in list which I got in last iteration.
but getting error on this line,
**"List Index Out Of Range"**

Here "A" is a column in dataframe df.

Comment: you havent initialized the list with any elements and trying to get an element. that is why, "List Index Out Of Range". be more clear on what you want

Comment: but also if I am giving _LIST[0]='' AFTER _list=[] I am getting error on that line only

Comment: @gsamaras ofcourse. But I believe OP missed the code where he is initialising the list. Otherwise it is pretty simple to see why the out of index error is coming. Thats why I asked him to be more clearer.

Comment: This code looks terrible. Why do you name variables like this? What are you actually trying to do? You should just use `_Var.isin(_LIST)`.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. 1) You list is empty 2) You have initialized "J" and then trying to use "j-1"  3) Your naming convention is not according to the PEP-8 or even generally accepted standards

Comment: First of all its a dummy code thats why I have named liked this, and I cannot use .isin(_List) , you can understand if you read my question

Comment: There is no `0` index of an empty list because would refer to the first item of the list, which doesn't exist. Just because you instantiate the lost doesn't mean you can index it until you put something in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing the index for which a list element does not exist

Answer (score 2):

`LIST` is empty (since you don't initialize it or populate in any way), thus the element you are indexing doesn't exist, which results in the error you witness.